# how to update the height of the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How to update the height of the iframe?

Parent.html

```
<iframe onload="iframeLoaded('settings')" id="settings" src="myIframe.html" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-style: none;width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

parent js

```
        function iframeLoaded(meth) {
            var iFrameID = document.getElementById(meth);
            if(iFrameID) {
                iFrameID.height = "";
                iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        }
```

---

1st load of myIframe.html

```
<button id="display_all">view more</button>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....</div>
```

after clicking the view more ing myIframe.html, the contents will display this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit morbi vel orci nisl. Sed sit amet maximus nulla. Nunc sit amet lectus non ante venenatis aliquam eget ut erat. Sed vitae gravida diam, ac pharetra magna. Nullam leo nibh, rhoncus eget arcu vel, hendrerit dapibus libero. Donec purus ligula, mollis quis erat a, aliquam pharetra tortor. 

Aenean et erat odio. Nullam vel diam felis. Phasellus a metus urna. Integer posuere, odio eget porta mollis, massa odio fringilla nibh, sed ultricies ipsum arcu vel risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 

Nullam condimentum, sem vel scelerisque dignissim, metus ligula imperdiet nisl, quis aliquet ex felis sed risus. Morbi gravida ultrices risus, at tincidunt mauris venenatis eget. 

Aenean et erat odio. Nullam vel diam felis. Phasellus a metus urna. Integer posuere, odio eget porta mollis, massa odio fringilla nibh, sed ultricies ipsum arcu vel risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 

Nullam condimentum, sem vel scelerisque dignissim, metus ligula imperdiet nisl, quis aliquet ex felis sed risus. Morbi gravida ultrices risus, at tincidunt mauris venenatis eget. 

Aenean et erat odio. Nullam vel diam felis. Phasellus a metus urna. Integer posuere, odio eget porta mollis, massa odio fringilla nibh, sed ultricies ipsum arcu vel risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 

Nullam condimentum, sem vel scelerisque dignissim, metus ligula imperdiet nisl, quis aliquet ex felis sed risus. Morbi gravida ultrices risus, at tincidunt mauris venenatis eget.
```

Now my problem is this, on the 1st load the height is ok (becaue of the js iframeLoaded) no vertical scroll is displayed, but when i click the view more button (to display other text) the vertical scroll appears.

How to resize the height of the iframe upon clicking the button (view more) inside the iframe, so that the vertical scroll will be removed?

Btw the the parent and iframe runs in the same url.

Let me know to you have questions to make it more clear.
Any help will be appreciated and I thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iframe:

```
$("display_all").click(function() {
    parent.$("body").trigger("eventName");
});
```

In the containing body

```
$("body").on("eventName", function() {
    $("#settings").height(yourHeightVal);
});
```